# integer frequency division

Tags: frequency, hardware

I have an 800 Hz square wave and would like to generate other frequency square waves from it: (100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700) Hz.

I'm aware of "divide by 2" frequency division, but how would you do something like divide by 7/8?

I plan for this project to be made from ICs (no programming). Chip suggestions are welcome :)

(Alternatively I could go from 100 Hz to the other frequencies, or go from 500 Hz, ect. I just need all of them present as outputs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two traditional exact approaches :

generate a high frequency representing the LCM of your required frequencies, and divide it to create the actual frequencies. Andy has illustrated this technique, and I suggest a modification that may make implementation easier.

The other is to divide the reference down to the GCD of your required frequencies (as they are all multiples of 100Hz and no higher frequency, 100Hz is the GCD) and multiply that.

The latter can be accomplished by generating a 100Hz signal rich in harmonics, then selecting all the required harmonics with a bank of bandpass filters. The first part of this is achieved by generating narrow spikes at a 100Hz repetition rate - the best approach to the second depends on your requirements : a "twin T" filter combined with a Q multiplier (such as a feedback loop around an opamp) can give an arbitrarily narrow passband; a traditional tuned L-C filter (or active equivalent) may be better if the reference frequency is variable across a narrow range.

A third approach is digital synthesis : sample the reference using a high frequency clock, and essentially implement one of the above approaches digitally. This is not exact; simple approaches introduce jitter of up to 1 clock period on each output ( summary: this can be mitigated with more complex calculations and a high resolution DAC).

Answer (score 3):

Use a phase locked loop.

It can multiply an input frequency by an integer quite easily. For instance, 800 Hz could be simply converted to 5600 Hz. Dividing this by 8 then gives you 700 Hz. The trick to obtaining all the frequencies you need is finding a frequency that can be divided by an integer to produce 300Hz, 500Hz and 700Hz. I believe this would be 84kHz.

If you divided this by 105 you get 800Hz so, construct a phase locked loop with input frequency of 800 Hz and output frequency 105 times higher

[image]

In the above diagram, REF is 800Hz and the output of the VCO (voltage controlled oscillator) is 84 kHz. The divider is a divide-by-105.

Comment: Stabilising a PLL with a divider of 105 could be ... somewhere between interesting and impossible (the latter if the 800Hz source is unstable). Two PLLs at 15/8 (for 1500Hz) and 7/8 (for 700Hz) may be easier : the first of these gives both 300 and 500Hz.

Comment: Why not go down to 100 and then up again? The numbers are much smaller then.

Comment: @CamilStaps - if you reduce 800 to 100 you'd need a PLL for 700, a PLL for 600, a PLL for 500 etc. because I believe all frequencies are required simultaneously.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that they were needed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that, if you do this with discrete logic, it's going to take a lot of ICs.

Andy aka's PLL approach is at the heart of if, and the IC you're interested in is the 74HC4046. This can be run from either 5 volts or 3.3 volts. The system would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD4ssv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And, except for the /2 functions, a /n would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkSEBo.png)</sup>

where SET0 to SET7 are found by subtracting 1 from n, converting to an 8-bit binary number, then inverting each bit. From this inverted binary number, SET0 is the least significant bit, and SET7 is the most significant bit.

If this seems like too many chips, and you only need one output frequency at a time, you can simplify the system to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ7kXO.png)</sup>

But here you have to provide a different set value for each different output frequency you want.

I've assumed that you want a square wave output for each frequency, which is why there is a /2 after each divider section.

Answer (score -1):

You could use 4017s with the reset pin connected to different numbered outputs, and then connect these to T flip flops. It would avoid feedback loops and filters, although depending on the flipflop package it could use up to 16 ICs.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question, which is about producing frequencies other than those that you can get by simple integer division.